# How do I disable semicolon warning?

Tags: vim-plugins

I'm using the [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) library with [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), but it throws a warning on every line regarding missing semicolons.  The semicolons are not required, or wanted.  How can I disable this feature?

I see from the [JSHint docs](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#relaxing-options) that I need to pass the `asi` option.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSHint documentation [Command-line Interface > Specifying Linting Options](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/#specifying-linting-options):

> The jshint executable is capable of applying linting options specified
>   in an external JSON-formatted file. Such a file might look like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "curly": true,
>   "eqeqeq": true,
>   "nocomma": true
> }
> ```
>
> jshint will look for this configuration in a number of locations,
>   stopping at the first positive match:
>
> 1. The location specified with the --config flag
> 2. A file named package.json located in the current directory or any parent of the current directory (the configuration should be declared
>      as the jshintConfig attribute of that file's JSON value)
> 3. A file named .jshintrc located in the current directory or any parent of the current directory
> 4. A file named .jshintrc located in the current user's "home" directory (where defined)

So in your .json configuration file include:

```
"asi": true
```

Comment: Great! `~/.jshintrc` works like a charm! I also found `"esversion":6` to be useful.